# How to show dynamic info in the rows of Element UI's Table

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, element, element-ui

So, basically I have a table like this.

```html
<v-table :data="data">
  <v-table-column prop="data.attribute" label="Attribute">
  </v-table-column>
 </v-table>
```

But instead of showing `data.attribute` in the column's rows, I want to do something like...

`return data.attribute === x ? 'Attribute equals X' : 'Attribute doesn't equal X'`

The reason behind this is because translations. The values that the column's rows are showing are actually the variables that store the translations. I tried to experiment with the scope to try to understand the table better doing something like this:

```html
<v-table-column prop="data.attribute" label="Attribute">
  <template slot-scope="scope">
    <input type="text" v-model="scope.row.attribute">
  </template>
</v-table-column>
```

Aaaand that just does nothing but create the input field but the data doesn't appear binded to it.
I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just noticed I was being retarded. The prop is `data.attribute`, so in this line:

`<input type="text" v-model="scope.row.attribute">`

I just had to add:

`<input type="text" v-model="scope.row.data.attribute">`

I need sleep. Anyway so this way it is also possible to do something like:

`<p>{{ scope.row.data.attribute }}</p>`

That's it as long it is inside the template with the slot-scope.

Hope it is useful to someone.